# Using Keyframe from react-native-reanimated causes app crash

Tags: react-native, css-animations, react-native-reanimated

Just upgraded "react-native-reanimated" to v3.6.1 and now all my Keyframe animations make the app crash without showing any error even on emulator.

```
 export const SampleKeyframe = new Keyframe({
  from: {
    transform: [{ rotate: '0deg' }],
  },
  to: {
    transform: [{ rotate: '45deg' }],
  },
});
```

Using it in a simple animated view

**UPDATE:** It seems that "transform" is whats causing the crash as using other props like "opacity" works. Still can't figure out why transform doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, which blocks me to upgrade from Expo v49 to v50 with all related libs. Still figuring out.

I have rewritten some animations using `useAnimatedStyle` instead of `Keyframe`, so some issues gone (even with using `transform`), but I don't want to abandon all Keyframe usages at all, that's not a soluion.

Answer (score 0):

if you add 'worklet' in makeKeyframeKey function, it will resolve your crash.

File: Reanimated/src/reanimated2/layoutReanimation/animationBuilder/Keyframe.ts

function makeKeyframeKey(index: number, transformProp: string) {
'worklet';
return `${index}_transform:${transformProp}`;
}

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue but I was able to resolve it by upgrading my package version to `3.7.0` and higher.
If you are using an Expo project, manually increase the version number in the `package.json` file

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/pull/5454#issuecomment-1972894376

Hope this helps!